# How to pass parameter into [routerLink] in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a variable called `userId` and i would like to pass that as a parameter in `[routerLink]`. userId is getting assigned a value before `<li>` is created. I have tried interpolation `{{}}` but it didnt help.

```
//header.component.ts
onAuth(form : NgForm) {
jForm = JSON.stringify(form); 
this.httpService.authMe(form.value)
.subscribe( 
  function(response) { 
    this.userId = response.userId; 
    console.log("Success Response" + response.userId)
  }
)
}

//header.component.html
<li *ngIf = "userId"><a [routerLink]="['/user', userId]">Account Settings</a></li>
```

Comment: If you want to use `this`, don't use `function()`, use instead `() => { this...}`. Besides that it should work as you have it. What's the problem?

Comment: I get undefined, are you talking about first or second "this"

Comment: The `this` inside `function() { ... }`

Comment: what about the "response" parameter?

Comment: What do you mean? arrow function is only about `this` to keep working

Comment: Is this what you are suggesting?                                       
`.subscribe( 
  response => {
    this.userId = response.userId; 
    console.log("Success Response" + response.userId)
  }
)`

Comment: yes . . . . . . . .  .

Comment: Why *ngIf is not updating `userId`?

Comment: Also not with my suggestion?

Comment: working now thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear . . .